# Hide UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uialertview

Is there a way to hide the UIAlertView programatically. I am displaying a progress view in mine and when the progress view is = 1.0 I want to hide the UIAlertView.

Answer (score 7):

What you can do is observe (using key-value observing) the `progress` attribute in your progress view, then when it hits 1.0 send the `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` message to the alert view.

Answer (score -2):

I would use a UIActionSheet to do this kind of behavior.  The user is trained to manually dismiss the UIAlertView and this would just confuse them.

UIActionSheets are highly customizable to do whatever you need.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically dismiss an action sheet

Comment: And users aren't trained to manually dismiss action sheets? They're functionally almost identical, just used for different purposes and appear in different places in the UI. You may be thinking of a modal view controller.

Comment: As another user has already stated in a separate posting...Apple's own commercial: http://www.apple.com/iphone/gallery/ads/#office-large does this.  Watch it until the commercial gets to the printing of a label.  What the iPhone app does (quite correctly in my opinion) is to put up a "Printing" message in a progress alert.  This is because sending the information to the printer/printing process may take a bit of time.

Comment: You shouldn't be using either a UIAlertView or UIActionSheet for this.